# How to undeploy the weblogic application using ant task?

Tags: deployment, ant, weblogic

I have to deploy my application in weblogic through ant.
what i am doing is:

```
<target name="deployOnServer1" >
        <echo>*********** Start deploying war file on SERVER1 *********** </echo>
        <wldeploy action="redeploy"
            source="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}.war" 
            name="${wls.appname}"      
            user="${wls1.user}" 
            password="${wls1.password}" 
            adminurl="${wls1.adminurl}"      
            targets="${wls1.targets}"
            verbose="true" 
            debug="true" 
            upload="true"
            remote="true"
        />
</target>
```

This deploys my application on weblogic, only if there is not any other application with same application context.
So what i did is:

```
 <target name="undeployOnServer1">
            <echo>*********** Start unDeploying war file on SERVER1 *********** </echo>
        <wldeploy
        action="undeploy" verbose="true" debug="true"
         name="${wls.appname}"
        user="${wls1.user}" password="${wls1.password}" 
        adminurl="${wls1.adminurl}"      
        failonerror="false" 

        />
  </target>
```

and changed the **deployOnServer1** target as

```
<target name="deployOnServer1" depends="undeployOnServer1">
```

but Now on undeploy it says, 
  no application named 'myapp' to undeploy
and on deploy it says,
  unable to deploy as there is other application with same context path '/myapp'.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [sample build.xml files for wldeploy](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/programming/wldeploy.html#wp1000506) from the [wldeploiy Ant Task Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/programming/wldeploy.html), the `targets` attribute needs to be specified (unless the application is deployed on the Administration Server instance):

```
  <target name="undeploy">
    <wldeploy
      action="undeploy" verbose="true" debug="true"
      name="DeployExample"
      user="weblogic" password="weblogic"
      adminurl="t3://localhost:7001" targets="myserver"
      failonerror="false" />
  </target>
```

This is the description of the `targets` attribute:

> The list of target servers to which
>   the application is deployed.
>  The
>   value of this attribute is a
>   comma-separated list of the target
>   servers, clusters, or virtual
>   hosts.
>  If you do not specify a
>   target list when deploying an
>   application, the target defaults to
>   the Administration Server
>   instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this property is missing:
    targets="${wls1.targets}"